# How can I return a value to a superclass without overriding the parent function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-3.5, metaclass

I would like to define a function with the same name as its parent which returns a value that the parent can receive and use. Although I think it may be possible to achieve this with a metaclass, I am unsure how one would do so (assuming it is possible) and whether or not there is a better, cleaner solution.

My desired format is shown below. The `Child` class will be defined by a developer other than myself, so I would like as few restrictions as possible. (For example, I would ideally like to not use `super(Child).f(a)` to replace `return a`.) I am also unsure how one could use keyword arguments with my model, which would be preferable.

```
class Parent:
    def f(self, arg):
        print("Received {}.".format(arg))
        return arg ** 3

class Child(Parent):
    def f(self, c, b, a):
        print(a, b, c)
        return a

# Prints "2 1 0" and "Received 2.". Sets value to 8.
value = Child().f(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: Prints `2 1 0` on python 2.7 and 3.4

Comment: If you define a method in a subclass with the same name, then by definition you override the parent method. I'm pretty sure what you want to do is impossible and would be a bad idea anyway. I suggest that you have `f` in the parent call some abstract method `g` which the child is responsible for overriding.

Comment: Note that it would just be `return super().f(a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a key issue with this statement:

> I would like to define a function **with the same name as** its parent which returns a value that the parent can receive

May I ask, why is this necessary?

the `f` in the Child class is completely different then `f` in the Parent class so naming them the same thing is extremely confusing even if you do get it to work.

Lets say I wrote the child class using your `Parent`:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def f(self):
        return 2
```

I would expect `Child().f()` to return 2, but if you are adding hidden logic behind the scenes that adds `arg ** 3` then I will instead get 8 and be wholly confused and cursing your library for adding very non-intuitive rules.

---

Instead why not have one function that is used and define the extra logic helper function in subclasses:

```
class Parent:
    def f(self, *v_args):
        arg = self.helper_f(*v_args)
        print("Received {}.".format(arg))
        return arg ** 3

    def helper_f(self,*args):
        "really should be an abstract method, must be implemented in a subclass"
        raise NotImplementedError("Must override in a subclass!") 

class Child(Parent):
    def helper_f(self, c, b, a):
        print(a, b, c)
        return a

# Prints "Received 2.". Sets value to 8.
value = Child().f(0, 1, 2)
```

Of course, yes, you technically **can** automate this with meta class.  But again, this would be **wholly confusing** to anyone using your `Parent` class

```
class Child_Method_Redirector(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, cls_dict):
        if bases is not ():
            if "f" in cls_dict:
                cls_dict["_auto_renamed_helper_f"] = cls_dict["f"]
                del cls_dict["f"]
        return type.__new__(meta,name,bases,cls_dict)


class Parent(metaclass=Child_Method_Redirector):
    def f(self, *v_args):
        arg = self._auto_renamed_helper_f(*v_args)
        print("Received {}.".format(arg))
        return arg ** 3

class Child(Parent):
    def f(self):
        return 2

# now it does Print "Received 2." and Sets value to 8.
value = Child().f()
```

But **Please Don't Do This**, it goes against [the zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

> Explicit is better than implicit.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

Comment: as a side note I'd like to point out that "can implement a special method that is called under <...> curcumstances" is fairly common convension, just think of a `dict` subclass overriding `__missing__`